# Drupal: how can I add text areas to my menus?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can I add text areas to my menus with Drupal ?

For example see lancelmaat.nl Menu > Contact... I would like to put some text to a submenu and edit it from backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're have the wrong approach.

Instead, make those boxes blocks, have them in a left sidebar and hide them with JS. When the menu item is hovered, show it.

It's rather easy to achieve that using jQuery, which comes bundled with Drupal.

Comment: I'm actually having problems with fade in / fade out events on the block. So basically, I've added a fadeOut event to both Contact menu item and Block, but the block has some children and when I move the mouse over the children, the fade out event is triggered

Comment: You mean that you want to fade out the block when you move your mouse out of it? Instead of using the mouseover event, use the hover() function (http://api.jquery.com/hover/). That should do the trick.